# Ng-click No getter for 'clickHandler' in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Trying to get a simple click handler working, and it's proving to be quite frustrating. The application is just a test application to try out different Angular.Dart features. - Using Dart 1.6 and Angular 1.0 and running in Dartium -

Clicking the button throws the error.
Ng-click No getter for 'clickMe'. But data binding on the input and label works perfectly fine.

Sample code

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular/application_factory.dart';

class TestMod extends Module {
  TestMod() {
    bind(ToggleComponent);
  }
}

@Component(selector: 'toggle-comp', templateUrl: "test.html", publishAs: 'toggle')
class ToggleComponent {

  String name = "";

  @NgTwoWay('rating')
  int rating;

  ToggleComponent() {

  }

  void clickMe() {
    print("Click");
  }
}




void main() {
  applicationFactory()
      ..addModule(new TestMod())
      ..run();
}
```

test.html file - where the binding works for ng-model but not for ng-click

```dart
<div>
<h3>Hellos {{name}} {{rating}}!</h3>
  Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <button ng-click="clickMe()">Click me</button>
</div>
```

and lastly here is the index.html file

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>AngularDartTest</title>

    <script async type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <toggle-comp rating="5"></toggle-comp>
  </body>
</html>
```

Stacktrace when you hit the button

```dart
No getter for 'clickMe'.

STACKTRACE:
#0      StaticClosureMap.lookupGetter (package:angular/core/parser/static_closure_map.dart:14:25)
#1      StaticClosureMap.lookupFunction (package:angular/core/parser/static_closure_map.dart:25:26)
#2      ClosureMapLocalsAware.lookupFunction.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/parser/parser.dart:253:44)
#3      CallScope.eval (package:angular/core/parser/eval_calls.dart:27:25)
#4      _UnwrapExceptionDecorator.eval (package:angular/core/parser/parser.dart:117:30)
#5      BoundExpression.call (package:angular/core/parser/syntax.dart:59:36)
#6      NgEvent._initListener.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/directive/ng_events.dart:142:39)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:840)
#8      _ZoneDelegate.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:466)
#9      _onRunUnary.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/zone.dart:122:63)
#10     VmTurnZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:104:16)
#11     _onRunUnary (package:angular/core/zone.dart:122:17)
#12     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:748)
#13     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:656)
#14     _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:682)
```

Comment: Maybe email angulardart@googlegroups.com ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that angular transformer is having trouble finding test.html, thus not extracting the clickMe getter. Getters get generated only if we see the symbol in an expression in a template.

By getter I mean the mapping `"clickMe": (o) => o.clickme`. You can always check all the getters/setters we have generated in `main_static_expressions.dart`.

The transformer should be fixed (PRs are very welcome), but in the mean time there are a number of ways to force the generation of the getter:

1. use exportExpressions. [docs](https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular-core-annotation.Directive@id_exportExpressions)
2. use html_files in the pubspec.yaml. [docs](https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular-app)
3. put your component and its template in the lib directory.

P.S. In angular.dart v1.0 publishAs does nothing, as the expression evaluation context is the component itself. [docs](https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular-core-annotation.Directive@id_exportExpressions)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `name` works but I think `"toggle.clickMe()"` will work or remove the `publishAs` argument.

Comment: When I do remove publishAs, I still get the error "No getter for 'clickMe'."  However, when I try toggle.clickMe() without removing publishAs, I get the error No getter for 'toggle'.

Comment: And I am running this in Dartium, so its not dart2js causing this.

Comment: I have no idea but I'm out of practice in Angular.dart.

Comment: Thanks for the help though! At least I know I'm not going crazy :)